# Passing class instance into function

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to pass a pointer of Student class into a function for a binary tree, however I am getting an error saying that there is no function that contains the input parameter, I am thinking it is because I am passing in a object pointer but, I don't know how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

demo.cpp:
    #include

```
#include <fstream> //read files

 #include <cstdlib> //c standard library

 #include "ETree.h"

#include "Student.h"

#include <string>

using namespace assignment3;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
ETree<Student> * BinaryTree = new ETree<Student>();
delete BinaryTree;

ifstream input;
input.open("stuText.txt");

if (!input)
{
    cerr << "Text file not opened!";
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    string word;
    int num;
    Student* inst;
    while(input >> word >> num)
    {
        inst = new Student(word, num);
        BinaryTree->add(inst);
    }
}   
return 0;
}
```

ETree.h

```
#ifndef ETREE_H

#define ETREE_H

#include "BTNode.h"


 namespace assignment3
 {
 template <typename Student>

class ETree
{
    public:

    ETree();
    ETree(Student inst);

    ~ETree();

    bool add(Student inst);


    private:

        BTNode<Student>* rootPtr;
};
//template <typename object>
//std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Queue<object>& queue);
 }

 #include "ETree.template"

 #endif
```

ETree.template
(the relevant part)

```
template <typename Student>
bool ETree<Student>::add(Student inst)
{
    if(rootPtr == NULL)
    {
        rootPtr = new BTNode<Student>(inst);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return rootPtr->add(inst);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code, and the error, ad text. A vague description of both isn't very helpful.

Comment: Nobody can help you without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Your title says "instance" but the question says "pointer". Is there perhaps a function that expects an instance but you're passing it a pointer?

Comment: Did not finish writing the question and accidentally submitted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can work..
All the **classes and functions** are assumed, because of **insufficient data input** given by OP. I hope you mean that you want to pass **pointer of the object**.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class student
{ //whatever you want 
 };

 void pass_pointer (student* ptr)
 { // whatever you want
  }

 int main ()
 { 
     student* temp;
     pass_pointer (temp);
     return 0;
  }
```

You can follow the following method to program whatever you want to do, i mean binary tree, whatever....hope that your problem is solved.

**If this address your problem then kudos, if this doesnt answer what meant to ask please say so in the comments below, i will edit it accordingly.**

Comment: Thank you for the reply, not getting any errors this time! oh no i cant upvote bc everyone hates me sorry :(